# cygwin sshd fatal seteuid Invalid argument

Tags: cygwin, sshd

recently I'm unable to connect to cygwin sshd server. below is the output of ssh client in verbose

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 -vvvv
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/config
debug1: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'Gowtham'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VJlYVlARWd+ePWzrElRNWS6tQTifgP+2T/3H10VsJBI
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug1: Host '127.0.0.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

**Error Event Xml from cygsshd server:**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="sshd" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-06T07:15:22.035892700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11803</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Blizlac</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>sshd: PID 1920: fatal: seteuid 197609: Invalid argument</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I think the error started to show up after system update. How to fix this seteuid invalid argument error? I event tried downgrading the openssh server; it to throwed same error. How can I fix this?

Windows 10.0, Build 18363

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the initial user with which i've installed cygwin. Deleting all cygwin files and registry entries and reinstalling cygwin fixed the issue. I wish I knew exactly on what files i have to change user permissions. I hope someone answers it.